# Can you change the Yoast SEO Title manually?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, seo, yoast

[Yoast SEO Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UI58.png)

I want to change the seo title automatically when I install the plugin.

Is there a way to change the code in plugins folder?

From %Title% %Page% %Separator% %Site Title%
into %Title% %Separator% only

Answer (score 0):

As an expert at [www.websitedesignsauckland.com](https://www.websitedesignsauckland.com) i want to add. Yes, you can change the Yoast SEO title manually. Yoast SEO is a popular WordPress plugin that provides various SEO features, including the ability to customize titles and meta descriptions.

To change the Yoast SEO title manually, follow these steps:

Log in to your WordPress dashboard.

Go to the post or page for which you want to change the SEO title.

Scroll down to the Yoast SEO section below the content editor.

Click on the "Edit snippet" button.

In the "SEO Title" field, you can manually enter the desired title for the page or post. Make sure to keep it concise, relevant, and optimized for your target keywords.

Yoast SEO will provide a real-time preview of how the title will appear in search engine results. You can see how it looks on desktop and mobile devices.

Once you have made the desired changes to the SEO title, click on the "Close snippet editor" button to save your changes.

Don't forget to update or publish your post/page to ensure the changes take effect on your live website.

By manually changing the Yoast SEO title, you have more control over how your content appears in search engine results. It allows you to optimize the title for better visibility, click-through rates, and SEO performance.